# Autofac vs. Structuremap, how do I inject all instances of an interface?

Tags: structuremap, autofac

In autoFac, I can register multiple implementation of an interface. When autofac instantiates my object, all instances are passed to the constructor.

From autofac’s documentation: [here](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/RelationshipTypes)

> For example, when Autofac is injecting a constructor parameter of type
>   IEnumerable it will not look for a component that supplies
>   IEnumerable. Instead, the container will find all
>   implementations of ITask and inject all of them.

Is this functionality available in StructureMap?

For my classes:

```
public interface IFoo
{

}

public class Foo1 : IFoo
{

}

public class Foo2 : IFoo
{

}

public class UsingFoo
{
    public UsingFoo(IEnumerable<IFoo> allFoos)
    {
        foreach (var foo in allFoos)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

How do I register my implementations, so that when UsingFoo is instantiated, the constructor will be passed all implementations of IFoo?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In StructureMap you can do:

```
ObjectFactory.Intialize(x => x.Scan(y => y.AddAllTypesOf<IFoo>()));
```

That will register all types of `IFoo`

Then when you resolve `UsingFoo`, they will be injected.

Edit:

I just quickly wrote this up in a console app:

```
ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
{
    x.Scan(y =>
    {
        y.AddAllTypesOf<IFoo>();
    });
});

var usingFoo = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<UsingFoo>();
```

Edit:

You made me doubt myself, so I double checked.

It works fine.

Here's a working example I quickly wrote in a console app:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    string Text { get; }
}

public class Foo1 : IFoo
{
    public string Text
    {
        get { return "This is from Foo 1"; }
    }
}

public class Foo2 : IFoo
{
    public string Text
    {
        get { return "This is from Foo 2"; }
    }
}

public class Bar
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<IFoo> _myFoos;

    public Bar(IEnumerable<IFoo> myFoos)
    {
        _myFoos = myFoos;
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        foreach (var myFoo in _myFoos)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(myFoo.Text);
        }
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
        {
            x.UseDefaultStructureMapConfigFile = false;
            x.Scan(y =>
            {
                y.TheCallingAssembly();
                y.AddAllTypesOf<IFoo>();
            });
        });

        var myBar = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<Bar>();

        myBar.Execute();

        Console.WriteLine("Done");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

The output is:

> This is from Foo 1
>
> This is from Foo 2
>
> Done

Comment: I don' tthink your are right. This will only inject one instance of IFoo. I need SM to inject all instances of IFoo as an IEnumerable<IFoo>.